# Get X-coordinates for bars in chart.js 4

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I use Chart.js v4.2.1

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bar chart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="barchart"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById('barchart');
    var chart = new Chart(canvas,
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data:
        {
            labels: ["Audi", "VW", "KIA"],
            datasets:
            [
              {
                  label: "Cars",
                  backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f"],
                  data: [2601, 4769, 602],
               },
            ],
        },
    });
</script>
</html>
```

To get number of bars I execute chart.data.datasets[0].data.length and get 3.
To get the Y-value for the first bar I do chart.data.datasets[0].data[0] and get 2601.

***How do I get the X-values (X-coordinates) for the bars?***
(I am not interested in using any plugin).

**Added:**
Here is a sample where chart.scales.x is defined but chart.scales.y is not.
This happen when I add yAxisID which I need in my complete work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bar chart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="barchart"></canvas>
        <div id="debug"></div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById('barchart');
    var chart = new Chart(canvas,
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data:
        {
            labels: ["Audi", "VW", "KIA"],
            datasets:
            [
                {
                    label: "Cars",
                    backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f"],
                    data: [2601, 4769, 602],
                    yAxisID: "cars",
                },
            ],
        },
        options:
        {
            scales:
            {
                cars:
                {
                    position: "left",
                    ticks:
                    {
                        color: "red",
                    },
                    grid:
                    {
                        display: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    });
    var dataSets = chart.data.datasets;
    var xPos = chart.scales.x.getPixelForValue(dataSets[0].data[0]);
    try
    {
        var yPos = chart.scales.cars.getPixelForValue(dataSets[0].data[0]);    // --> here y is undefined
        document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "xPos=" + xPos + ", yPos=" + yPos;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "xPos=" + xPos + "<br>" + e;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code: `chartInstance.scales.x.getPixelForValue(chart instance.data.labels[labelIndex]`

Comment: That worked. How do I get the Y-coordinates? 
chartInstance.scales.y.getPixelForValue(chartInstance.data.labels[labelIndex]) 
does not work, y is not defined in that context.

Comment: chartInstance.scales.y should be available, if not please add a reproducable sample. but you should not use the labels array for this, you need to use this: `chartInstance.scales.y.getPixelForValue(chartInstance.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[dataIndex])`

Comment: Ok, I've added a sample where y is undefined.

Comment: This is because you override the default y axis with a scale named `cars` so you need to replace `y` with `cars` in the code

Comment: Thanks! Everything's working in may main project now.